# Table of sections with CellPrint

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

I am trying to produce a table of sections with each section containing a `DynamicModule`. My two questions are: (1) How do I produce grouped sections that are folded shut? (2) How do I stop the text in my `DynamicModule` from having quotes around it?

Here is a toy code for the dynamic module

```
ClearAll[f];
f[a_] := DynamicModule[{x = 0.5}, 
 Column[{
  "Plot " <> ToString[a], 
  Slider[Dynamic[x]], 
  Dynamic[
   Plot[Sin[a x t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
  ]
  }]
  ]
```

I now do a table to produce the sections

```
Table[
CellPrint[TextCell["Section " <> ToString[i], "Subsection"]];
CellPrint[f[i]],
{i, 3}];
```

The output is open cells and extra quotes around the strings. How do I `CellPrint` folded cells and get rid of the extra quotes"?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What do you mean by `are folded shut`?

Comment: @Kuba When you double click on the right bracket you open and shut the cells. I call this folding to avoid a clash with the option CellOpen

Comment: @Kuba Thank you for solving my question 2. How about solving my question 1? I will certainly accept it if you can do this?

Comment: Sorry for delay. I think the answer should fit your needs now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CellGroupData` with `1` as the second argument for creation of cell groups where only first cell is open:

```
Do[NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   Cell@CellGroupData[{Cell["Section " <> ToString[i], "Subsection"], 
      Cell[ToBoxes@ExpressionCell@f[i], "Output"]}, 1]], {i, 3}];
```

[image: screenshot]

The quotes around the text are not shown because I have specified the `"Output"` style for the cells containing `DynamicModule` (this style sets `ShowStringCharacters->False` option for `Cell`).

Comment: I had not seen CellGroupData before. Thanks for this.