# How to implement specific cell grouping behavior?

Tags: cells

Here's the situation in my *Mathematica* Notebook:

[image]

I'd like the bottom cell to be grouped with the cells above it. Here are those same cells toggled into code:

```
 Cell["How to get new text cells to group right?", "ItemNumbered",
 WholeCellGroupOpener->True,
 CellGroupingRules->{GroupTogetherGrouping, 10000.}]

Cell["This is text...", "Text",
 CellGroupingRules->{GroupTogetherGrouping, 10000.}]

Cell["This is code...", "Program",
 CellGroupingRules->{GroupTogetherGrouping, 10000.}]

Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"why", " ", "am", " ", "I", " ", "not", " ", "in", " ", "the", " ", 
  RowBox[{"group", " ", ":", "("}]}]], "Input",
 CellGroupingRules->{GroupTogetherGrouping, 1001.}]
```

I have cell grouping set to **Manual Grouping** in the **Cell ► Grouping** menu.

---

#### Update

Let me clarify what I'm trying to achieve:

Following the solution of @PatrickStevens changes nothing unless I switch to `Automatic` change grouping to grouping in the **Cell** dropdown menu. However, doing this breaks other cell groups that I created manually:

[image]

So how can I set a notebook to automatically obey these grouping rules:

1. If the cell type is in {"Text", "Item", "Code", "Input", "Output", and "Program"} then group it together under a header cell.
2. The header cell (the top cell in a cell group) is the first cell found above of this type, *checked in this order*: "SubitemNumbered", "ItemNumbered", "Subsection", "Section", "Subtitle", "Title".

Comment: I don't think I'm using CellGroupingRules correctly.

Comment: Do you print all the `Cell`s which should be grouped at once or one by one? In the first case [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84076/280) answer is relevant, in the second - [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47231/280) is related.

Comment: Related: "[Making cells group](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6019/280)."

Answer (score 2):

> I have cell grouping set to **Manual Grouping** in the **Cell ► Grouping** menu.

The Documentation clearly [states](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellGrouping.html):

> - With `CellGrouping -> Automatic`, cells are automatically grouped in a hierarchical way based on their styles.
> - With `CellGrouping -> Manual`, cells must be grouped manually, either by setting up explicit `CellGroupData` expressions, or by using the
>     **Group Cells** menu item in the notebook front end.

So by selecting **Manual Grouping** in the **Cell ► Grouping** menu you have disabled automatic cell grouping. You have no way to get automatic cell grouping if you explicitly disable it!

---

> Following the solution of @PatrickStevens changes nothing unless I
>   switch to `Automatic` change grouping to grouping in the **Cell**
>   dropdown menu. However, doing this breaks other cell groups that I
>   created manually

After switching to `CellGrouping -> Automatic` you will be able to recreate your manual cell groups. Unfortunately I don't know an easy way to preserve manual cell groups during the transition from `CellGrouping -> Manual` to `CellGrouping -> Automatic`. I can only suggest to tag the `Cell`s in your manually created groups and then after the transition to recreate the groups through finding and selecting tagged `Cell`s and grouping them again, all this can be done programmatically.

---

> I don't think I'm using `CellGroupingRules` correctly.

Possible values of the option `CellGroupingRules` are mostly undocumented. You can find them via the Options Inspector:

[image: screenshot]

In [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2000/Feb/msg00126.html) 2000 year MathGroup post P.J. Hinton from Wolfram Research provided some explanations:

> You can change the cell grouping precedences as defined in the
>   notebook's style sheet.  This will give you the means of directing the
>   front end to use your preferences as "automatic grouping".
>
> The decision as to whether a collection of cells will be grouped under
>   a single bracket is determined by the option setting `CellGroupingRules`
>   that resides within the style definition used by the cell.  Option
>   values  take the form
>
> ```
>     <grouping rule name>
>
>     {<grouping rule name>, <integer between 0 and 100>}
> ```
>
> Grouping rule names that use strings only include `"InputGrouping"`,
>   `"OutputGrouping"`, and `"GraphicsGrouping"`.  Grouping rule names that
>   use strings with numbers include `"TitleGrouping"` and
>   `"SectionGrouping"`.  The numbers indicate a precedence level with 0
>   being highest and 100 being lowest.
>
> In general, if adjacent cells have styles which use the same grouping
>   rule name, the cells will be grouped only if the preceding cell has a
>   higher precedence level.  Consider the placement of these two cells
>   together.
>
> ```
>     Cell["cell A", CellGroupingRules->{"TitleGrouping", 10}]
>
>     Cell["cell B", CellGroupingRules->{"TitleGrouping", 20}]
> ```
>
> These cells will be grouped together because the prior cell will have
>   higher precedence.  However, the following cells will not group
>   because the precedence levels are reversed.
>
> ```
>     Cell["cell A", CellGroupingRules->{"TitleGrouping", 20}]
>
>     Cell["cell B", CellGroupingRules->{"TitleGrouping", 10}]
> ```
>
> Things get a little more complicated when cells of unlike grouping
>   rules begin to appear next to one another.  The rules here are:
>
> 1) `"TitleGrouping"` groups with any other cell that appears below it.
>
> 2) `"SectionGrouping"` groups with any other cell that appears below it
>   with the exception of those cells which have "Title" grouping.
>
> 3) `"InputGrouping"`, `"OutputGrouping"`, and `"GraphicsGrouping"` don't
>   grop with any cells that appear after them.
>
> Finally, if a pair of cells group together, but a third, preceding
>   cell does not group with the first cell in the pair, then the pair
>   will for its own cell subgroup.

In [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Jul/msg00913.html) 2007 year MathGroup post one of the users summarized own findings on the subject. These findings are obviously incomplete and partially incorrect but since there is a lack of such information I'll cite them here:

> Here is what I have managed to infer so far (no guarantees that I got
>   it right, as these features are unfortunately undocumented).
>
> `CellGroupingRules` can be one of the following:
>
> `"NormalGrouping"` → Appears to be essentially no grouping
>
> `{"TitleGrouping", _Integer}` → See `"SectionGrouping"`
>
> `{"SectionGrouping", _Integer}` → For `"TitleGrouping"` and
>   `"SectionGrouping"`, it appears grouping is mostly controlled by the
>   Integer (I read somewhere it needs to be in the range of 0 to 100, but
>   have not tested this.) Lower integers have higher priority, so a
>   higher integer group becomes nested within the lower integer group. If
>   a new lower integer cell is found, it then starts its own group. The
>   `"TitleGrouping"` vs `"SectionGrouping"` part seems to influence the
>   behaviour only if you have a "SectionGrouping" immediately followed by
>   a `"TitleGrouping"` of lower precendence (ie higher integer). In that
>   case, the `"TitleGrouping"` is ignored. `"TitleGrouping"` appears to have
>   one more (ANNOYING) "feature". If it does not have any cells in its
>   group, it adds some space to the bottom cell margin. I have not found
>   an option to control or turn this off.
>
> `"InputGrouping"` → Group with cell below if it has style `"Output"`,
>   otherwise no grouping
>
> `"OutputGrouping"` → Group with cell above if it has style `"Input"` or
>   `"Output"`. (By implication, will group will cell below if cell below
>   has Style `"Output"`)
>
> `"GraphicsGrouping"` → I think this is now legacy as graphics have style
>   `"Output"` in version 6. Presumably still used if you turn on legacy
>   graphics.
>
> `"GroupTogetherGrouping"` → This is new to version 6, and I am not sure
>   how it works yet and whether or not it needs an _Integer like
>   `"TitleGrouping"` and `"SectionGrouping"`.
>
> `"GroupTogetherNestedGrouping"` → Also new to version 6. Also not sure
>   how it works.
>
> I would be interested in hearing what others have inferred, or if they
>   have any other ideas on how to achieve printing "without the code".
>
> Derek

Also citing [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92491/280) answer, `"GroupTogetherNestedGrouping"` is intended "to stay in the same grouping space as list stuff normally resides (look into the Default stylesheet at "Styles for Body Text > Display > Lists > Bulleted")".

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `CellGroupingRules` correctly. It groups by the number you provide it. Change `1001.` to `10000.` and it works.

Comment: Check out my edits